# Magento 1.9 product edit page add tab and grid inside that tab

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs, product-grid

I created simple custom module, from that i need to add a custom tab with grid in admin product edit page.

Still now I achieved the tab using following code.

### notification.xml(admin layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>Customer Watch</name>
                <block>augment_notification/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

### Tab.php(block)

```
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return $this->__('Customer Watch');
}
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return $this->__('Customer Watch');
}
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}
public function getTabUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/watchlist', array('_current' => true));
}
public function getTabClass()
{
    return 'ajax';
}
```

}

I want to know how to custom grid implemented with in this custom tab.
Thanks in advance for your idea and help.
[image]

Comment: hope this will help you guys https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82159/magento-2-how-to-add-grid-to-the-tab-in-customer-index-edit

Comment: hope this will help you guys https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82159/magento-2-how-to-add-grid-to-the-tab-in-customer-index-edit

Comment: @PradeepKumar have you check the tags?  Que is for magento 1.9 and you are suggesting answer for magento 2!