# Create tab and insert custom grid inside tab

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, tabs

I created a grid by following this [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/), I would like to create 4 grids more, the problem is I need to add all these grids to tab

so far I've created a controller to load the block like this:

```
class Lime_Customgrid_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Custom'))->_title($this->__('Custom Lime'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('sales/sales');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('lime_customgrid/adminhtml_table_custom'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> Block > Adminhtml > Table > Custom > Custom.php:

```
<?php
class Lime_Customgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Table_Custom extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('custom_tabs');
        // $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('lime_customgrid')->__('Custom tabs'));
    }


    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTab(
            'form_listing',
            array(
                'label'   => Mage::helper('lime_customgrid')->__('Listing'),
                'title'   => Mage::helper('lime_customgrid')->__('Listing'),
                'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'lime_customgrid/adminhtml_table_custom_tab_grid'
                )
                ->toHtml(),
            )
        );

        $this->addTab(
            'form_attributes_listing',
            array(
                'label'   => Mage::helper('lime_customgrid')->__('Set Attributes'),
                'title'   => Mage::helper('lime_customgrid')->__('Set Attributes'),
                'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'lime_customgrid/adminhtml_table_custom_tab_grid'
                )
                ->toHtml(),
            )
        );
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }


}
```

> Block > Adminhtml > Table > Custom > Tab > Grid.php:

```
<?php

class Lime_Customgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Table_Custom_Tab_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('lime_order_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
                'city'       => 'city',
                'country_id' => 'country_id'
            ))
            ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
                'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
            ))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'fullname',
                'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
                array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'products',
                '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                    FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                    WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                        AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
                array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
            )
        ;

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('lime_customgrid');
        $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

        $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Order #'),
            'index'  => 'increment_id'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('purchased_on', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Purchased On'),
            'type'   => 'datetime',
            'index'  => 'created_at'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('products', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Products Purchased'),
            'index'        => 'products',
            'filter_index' => '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table.entity_id = x.order_id AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('fullname', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Name'),
            'index'        => 'fullname',
            'filter_index' => 'CONCAT(customer_firstname, \' \', customer_lastname)'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('city', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('City'),
            'index'  => 'city'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('country', array(
            'header'   => $helper->__('Country'),
            'index'    => 'country_id',
            'renderer' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_country'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Customer Group'),
            'index'  => 'customer_group_code'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header'        => $helper->__('Grand Total'),
            'index'         => 'grand_total',
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currency
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Method'),
            'index'  => 'shipping_description'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('order_status', array(
            'header'  => $helper->__('Status'),
            'index'   => 'status',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportLimeCsv', $helper->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportLimeExcel', $helper->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

the result is so mess up, even when I click to load next pagination, it redirects me to admin dashboard:

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170233/magento-1-9-product-edit-page-add-tab-and-grid-inside-that-tab

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170233/magento-1-9-product-edit-page-add-tab-and-grid-inside-that-tab

Comment: hope this will help you guys https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82159/magento-2-how-to-add-grid-to-the-tab-in-customer-index-edit

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('lime_customgrid/adminhtml_table_custom'));
```

with the following

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('lime_customgrid/adminhtml_table_edit'))
     ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('lime_customgrid/adminhtml_table_custom'));
```

=> create edit.php file

```
<?php

class Lime_Customgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Table_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
 {
    /**
    * 
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'lime_customgrid';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_custom';

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just Check Below Link & Download that Module.

---

> https://github.com/webspeaks/productsgrid_magento2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/165196)

Comment: The Code is too long so i reffer that to send the link